# Assign a column value if it throws an exception in Linq query

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a query where one property is a path "/Primary/secondary/tertiary/.../.../"
My task is to split this path by the slashes, so every sub-path can be assigned as a property in the query result.
The problem is, that the length varies. Some paths have a post-split array length of 1, some of 7. So I need to have 7 different category columns:

```
var result = MySource.Where(ms => ...)
                     .Select(ms => new {
                        ID = ms.ID,
                        Name = ms.Name,
                        Category1 = ms.Path.Split('/')[0],
                        Category2 = ms.Path.Split('/')[1] //exception
                        ....                              //exception
                        Category7 = ms.Path.Split('/')[6] //exception
                     });
```

After the path gets split, the resulting array is of various length (1 - 7) leading into an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. How can I circumvent this exceptions?

I have tried using the nullcoalescence operator `ms.Path.Split('/')[1] ?? "N/A"`, which did not help, because there is no result but an exception thrown. Because of this every shorthand-if statement will fail as well.

Is there a way to catch the exception (wrap in try catch block?) so I can assign a default value if the array is out of bounds?

Comment: why don't you use a property of type Array or List  such as `public string[] Categories { get; set; }` ?

Comment: Do you REALLY need to have the categories split like this or can you use Selman22's suggestion? If you don't do it like this, you will have a world of pain ahead of you if you need to do changes like add another level in future.

Comment: because It is required to have every single category as a seperate column. And I don't know how many categories there are, so I need to do it dynamically. 
I had it as a collection before and let linqpad just export it to excel. But now they want it as described above. No way around it.

Comment: @Serv: `"And I don't know how many categories there are"` - All the more reason to use a collection instead of individual properties.  It sounds like there's a usage of this object outside the scope of this question which is pushing you into a less supportable design.  *That* usage needs to be re-thought, not this LINQ query.

Comment: What happens if you have 15 categories?

Comment: David I hear you, but since this is a One-Time requirement to transform SharePoint list data into a HumanResources-mind-readable format I won't argue with the customer about his needs.
@DavidG: Won't happen. I had a collection at first and checked the maximum length.

Comment: I guarantee you that the moment this code hits production, someone will find a way to make something with 8 or more categories...

Comment: @Serv: It's not a question of arguing with the customer about his needs, it's a question of fulfilling those needs in a robust and easily supportable way.  How "one time" is this?  They're just going to execute it once and then throw it away?  If that's the case, by all means throw together the easiest thing that works.  But in my experience that's *very rarely* the case.  Once it works, the customer is going to keep using it for years to come.  There are support and maintenance costs associated with that, and ignoring those does the customer a significant disservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
Category7 = ms.Path.Split('/').ElementAtOrDefault(6) ?? "N/A",
```

see demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4nTBhq

`ElementAtOrDefault` return the element at index (for example 6, like [6]) but if out of bound return null.

optimized, without calling Split multiple times:

```
   .Select(ms => {
      var categories = ms.Path.Split('/');
      return new {
          ID = ms.ID,
          Name = ms.Name,
          ...
          Category7 = categories.ElementAtOrDefault(6),
      };
    })
```

Comment: Wow ... I didn't even know this method existed! Perfect! (Answer will be excepted in 6 minutes )

Comment: I would avoid doing this as you are running the `Split` function 7 times (or once per category column) instead of once.

Comment: @DavidG added optimized version

Answer (score 3):

Your modeling seems a little broken.  Instead of a flattened set of properties, populate a single collection.  Something like this:

```
Select(ms => new {
    ID = ms.ID,
    Name = ms.Name,
    Categories = ms.Path.Split('/')
})
```

Going a step further, you can create an actual (non-anonymous) model to hold this information, encapsulating the logic of category range checking.  Something like:

```
Select(ms => new SomeObject(
    ms.ID,
    ms.Name,
    ms.Path.Split('/')
))
```

Then in `SomeObject` you can have all sorts of logic, for example:

In the constructor you can perform input checking on the values, including the count of categories supplied, to ensure the object is valid.

You can keep the collection of categories private and expose properties for 1-7 if you really need to, which internally perform this check.  (Though I really don't recommend that.  It creates an unnecessary point of change for something that's already handled by a collection, indexing values.)  Something like:

```
public string Category1
{
    get
    {
        if (categories.Length < 1)
            return string.Empty;
        return categories[0];
    }
}
```

Maybe throw an exception instead of returning an empty string?  Maybe do something else?  The point is to encapsulate this logic within an object instead of in a LINQ query or in consuming code.

Comment: why? you can use linq for transform data, no need to do oop everywhere.
 
The transformation from ``source -> something`` can be encapsulated in a function ( like a ``PrettyPrint(source, TextWrite``) ), but intermediate local types are ok i think

Comment: @EnricoSada Not having to rewrite your LINQ query when the number of categories changes for one reason.

Comment: @EnricoSada: Immediate local types do have their use, yes.  But the question then becomes what else is this type being used for?  And, more importantly, what responsibilities might force this to change in the future?  I suspect that other usage (not specified in the question) is indirectly driving this design and can be improved with a little encapsulation of logic.  At the very least, storing a collection in a flattened finite list of properties probably isn't the way to go.